# Background image not repeating

Tags: css

Ive been having troubles getting my background to repeat itself vertically.
CSS Code

```
html {
    background-color: black;
}
body {
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000;
    background-image:url("../images/background.png");
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

I can't figure it out. Please help! I've tried without quote, with quotes, full address... I'm stumped

There is content in the page. http://www.hott-source.com

Comment: [not related] `width: 1000px`.... not `width: 1000`.

Comment: Is your image in the right place?

Answer (score 1):

You have no height for the `body`, there's no content in it, so you can't see the `repeat-y` in effect.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a height which is at least the same size as your background image.

Answer (score 0):

You are repeating y so you need to give height for body. Or try loading with more content and check..effect may not be visible bcoz of no content.

Answer (score 0):

If you are giving any background image you should give both height and width for that.

```
height:100%; or min-height:500px;
width: 1000px;
```

Answer (score 0):

atleast give the min-height as the height of the background image.

```
 html {
        background-color: black;
    }
    body {
        margin: auto;
        width: 1000px;
        min-height:;//height of the image
        background:url("../images/background.png") repeat-y;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
#ContentPlacer { position: absolute; }
```

is causing the `#PageWrapper` and `body` to ignore most of your content height.

Remove that `position: absolute;`.

---

As a side note:

You might want to consider removing the `<img src="banner.jpg">` and put it as a background image into the `#Banner`. You can then position the menu easily on top of it by putting the `#Menu` it inside the `#Banner` element.